# Register entityFramework with MySql.Data 6.7.2.0 connector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, entity-framework-6, mysql.data

I have tried to configure my web project to use MySQL pre release of .net connectors, version 6.7.2.0. However, i keep getting this message, even if I try my best configure my project to use the 6.7.2.0 version of the connectors.

As it is now, I keep getting this errormessage:

> No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I have tried different ways to configure my Web.config file, and here is my current settings:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
             invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
             type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
  </entityFramework>
```

I have installed EF6 alfa3 from NuGet. Currently my connector has been installed manually from [this downloaded file](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.7.2-noinstall.zip/from/http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/mysql/), I tried to install it from NuGet repository, but with the exact same result.

Comment: My Advice is not use EF with Mono. If you need an ORM in Mono please use NHibernate that has full support in Linux. Normally the advices about run MVC in Mono is to remove the entity framework dll

Comment: Because EF will be supported in Mono as of version EF6, i would really like to stick to Entity Framework.
The error message I get is however in my Windows environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to registering the ADO.NET provider, you need to register the Entity Framework provider:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

You also need to ensure that the provider has been built against Entity Framework 6. See [this article](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6) for more information on this.

Comment: I had an error with a very similar message to the OP's. (Mine was `No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.`) @bricelam's answer fixes that error too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. After rolling back to EF5 and MySql Connector 5.6 and it still not working, I finally found a feed where someone had mentioned that they had to remove the version and culture reference in order to get it to work. No idea why. Here:

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
             invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
             type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
   <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
```